# multiple computers having issues with WLAN

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, dell-latitude

Dell Lattitude computer intermittently disconnecting from WiFi

Hey everyone, I've got around 7 users whose laptop is disconnecting frequently(every 30ish minutes) from the Internal WiFi
The computers are all Dell Lattitude e5430
In Event Viewer, the errors given are twofold, first an 11002 ID error, then a 8002 ID error.
The failure reason for both is always ReasonCode 229378, which translates to The driver disconnected while associating.

I've done the following:

- released and renewed ip
- flushed dns
- Winsock reset
- Full TCP/IP reset
- completely uninstall and re-install all drivers
- replace the NIC
- drop and re-add network (don't have any other networks nearby to test
  on)
- Have Dell wireless connection agent manage the wireless
  connection.(still happens)
- Swap to LAN hardline connection (LAN connection still drops (this
  really threw me))
- Disable IPv6(isn't used, didn't work, re-enabled it) updated all other drivers on the computer to most recent versions.
- Verify registry entries are set correctly for WLAN autoconfig service
- Manage the power settings so that the computer can't turn off the device in order to save power.

I've been searching far and wide, only post I've found thus far that was solved was because of a hardware issue, adapter was replaced. Which eventually I tried on the computer that's been receiving the issue the longest, and it did not resolve it.

I do not have access to the routers, the gateway, hub, etc. So I can't check any of those settings.

It started recently on around 8 computers (about two weeks ago) Users only lose access for 1-2 minutes (The WLAN service restarts, depending on it's configuration depends on how long it takes for the connection to come back.)

I'm absolutely stumped here, I keep looking but can't find anything else to try. Where else can I look to find answers? I've tried technet, general microsoft sites, and dell forums. Do you guys have any ideas for other troubleshooting aspects?

Computer is on Windows 7 SP1

Adapter is a Dell Wireless 1540 802.11 a/g/n (2.4 GHz/5GHz)

Comment: If these computers do not store any private or company related data I would try to use another network, ex. make a hotspot on your smartphone and test if the connection works. Otherwise talk to network admin to see what sort of funky stuff is happening with network. Btw, do you have other devices internally what do not have problems connecting to the current network?

Comment: This will almost certainly need to be looked at by a network administrator with the necessary authority to do proper troubleshooting on both ends.

Comment: @alljamin yeah we've got a lot of computers not having the issue, even the same model computers that were imaged and had the same drivers installed.

Cross checked the ones working with the ones not working, no differences with Microsoft update, no differences with dell updates, or even services running. 

Also unfortunately they all do have sensitive information, so I can't connect to another network.

Comment: @David, I've tried going to the network admin, they want me to explore every possible hardware avenue before bringing it back up to them.
Just trying to think of other things it could be.

Comment: You can give a try to external USB Wi-Fi modem and try connecting to the network. Does the company where you work in has different from this dell laptops? Do these laptops have the same issue as the one you've mentioned?

Comment: @alljamin The issue was with the Access Points, we did have other laptops that were not having issues. I swapped the WLAN card out from the working laptops onto one of the test laptops I acquired that was having the issue, when the WLAN cards were swapped out, the issue happened on the newer laptop(the ones that were previously working) and the issue disappeared from the previously non-working laptop.
After this, the network admin agreed to look into the issue on the network end and found the Access Points were intermittently kicking them off due to configuration settings he had set weeks ago

Comment: Great that you have found the answer. Please post your answer with details how your problem was solved so that other users would follow your guide to troubleshoot their problems.